# Is it possible to have an extra row for each item in kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to have an extra row for each item in kendo grid? I need to provide 2 values for each column.

I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can't you form the data to do this? or is the data external?

Comment: my data is formed, i do it manually, but I get always one value, tried with this: 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/multicolumnheaders but only view works, second value is not displayed well

Comment: Can you show us what the data looks like, I assume its JSON?

Comment: this data I have not yet, it is just screen shot of something, I created an array that I am pushing to my column fields

Comment: Can you show the code, you can just build you collection to the shape required and then push that to the grid.

Comment: thank you very much but I solved it, everything in one cell end just a call 2 columns using a template :)

Comment: You should use row template for that